# Can I send money from my VCC to PayPal?

Tags: money-transfer, paypal, balance-transfer, virtual-credit-card

I don't have a bank account due to several (personal) reasons, and I can't open one, but in some way (with help of my mobile service provider) I can have as many Virtual Credit Cards as I want. Those credit cards last 24 hours and can be used once. Any unused money isn't lost, and gets saved for me to reuse. However, every VCC costs money. I want to buy something from a website that uses PayPal as the only payment method. When I link the VCC to my PayPal account it gets marked as used and it gets disabled. How can I send money from my VCC to my PayPal account?

EDIT:
I heard about PayPal Cash card, can I buy it online?

Comment: Who is the VCC provider?

Comment: NBE(National Bank of Egypt), with help from Etisalat Egypt.

Comment: Here is the [FAQ for the service in English](http://www.etisalat.eg/etisalat/portal/support_en?supportTopic=1391419977779%20&supportSubtopic=1399994478402). But I couldn't find an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

If PayPal won't accept the VCC number, then by definition you can't do this.

If you want to know whether there's a way to get special permission or bypass that restriction... I'm afraid the right thing to do is ask PayPal. Yes, I know their customer support is awful, but this is a classic customer support question, and they know the internals of their system better than any of us possibly could.

Comment: Isn't there any other E-Money service that accepts adding funds without linking the credit card, and at the same time it's money can be transferred to PayPal?

Comment: That's a different question... I have no clue; I haven't investigated. Find them and ask. Or buy from businesses that can securely accept credit card numbers directly; the VCC should work for those.